# Tomcat unable to create file in dir owned by same group

Tags: permissions, java, group, tomcat

I have a server running Tomcat, and I need Tomcat to create a file in a particular folder.

Tomcat (technically a Java app) runs as the user 'tomcat', as evidenced by top:

```
#top
1251 tomcat    20   0 7427m 2.3g 9624 S  3.0 30.0 856:04.62 java
```

Part of my Tomcat code is to create a new file 'foo.txt' in '/foo/'

The user 'tomcat' is a member of group 'work', as evidenced by groups:

```
#groups tomcat
tomcat : tomcat work
```

The folder '/foo/' has these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 root work 4096 Oct  8 14:20 .
```

When Tomcat tries to create a file within that folder, he gets a 'permission denied' error.

HOWEVER, when I chown /foo/ to the tomcat *user*, it works fine.

SO, is Java somehow not able to utilize Group permissions?? Not likely, IMHO. 
What am I missing?

Comment: How are you starting `tomcat`? It sounds like it's not calling `initgroups()`, so the process doesn't get all its secondary groups enabled.

Comment: Also what's the distro? Contexts on the directory `/foo` may be blocking Tomcat from writing to this directory via SELinux. You can run `sealert` to see any pending alerts.

Comment: @slm - Selinux context causes the 'ls -l' command to show '.' sign at the end of the permission column. If Jon pasted real 'ls -l' output it looks like there isn't any selinux on this system. However if there isn't a selinux and the '/foo' directory realy lies at the / directory, I suggest to restart tomcat because it's possible the tomcat is not able to see a new group added when it was already started.

Comment: You did restart tomcat after adding tomcat to the "work" group?

Comment: @SebastianPiech - good point, I hadn't noticed the output was missing the dot denoting context at the end of the permissions bits. Though the lack of any contexts being applied to this directory may be the issue if SELinux is involved. It's still worth a look, IMO.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies!!  It's Centos 6.3.  `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` indicates that `SELINUX=disabled`.  I'm curious about `initgroups()` not starting; I'll look into that.  And, yes, Tomcat has been restarted, since adding it to the group 'work'.